# MID-FIND alias in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
# -- create a dataframe 
list_columns = ['weight', 'animal', 'age']
list_data = [
    [14, 'One Zebra co1 animal', 10],
    [4, '2 cats co2 domestic animal', 15],
    [100, '3 cats co1 domestic animal', 6],
    [400, 'horse co2 animal', 3]
    ]
df_animals = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

I want to create antoher column that contains the first 3 letters after  the string `co`.

In excel it would be something like `MID(F8;FIND("co";F8;3);3)` and it would return `co1 co 2 co1 co2`
I am almost sure this can be done with pandas but I did not find yet a way to do this.

If the starting point was fixed, I would do `df_animals['Test'] = df_animals['animal'].str[:2]`

But in my case is variable. Can someone direct me to the right path in acheiving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df_animals['new'] = df_animals['animal'].str.extract('(co\w{,3})')
print(df_animals)
```

**Output**

```
   weight                      animal  age  new
0      14        One Zebra co1 animal   10  co1
1       4  2 cats co2 domestic animal   15  co2
2     100  3 cats co1 domestic animal    6  co1
3     400            horse co2 animal    3  co2
```

The idea is to capture the first 3 word characters (`\w{,3}`) if they exists after `co`.